# In mdframed package, mdfdefinestyle and newmdtheoremenv give different results

Tags: mdframed

I would expect that the following two ways of defining a theorem environment give the same result. But they do not: the first environment puts a new paragraph after "Theorem 1", the second one does not. Can you please help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{thmastyle}{linewidth=2}
\mdtheorem[style=thmastyle]{thma}{Theorem}
\newmdtheoremenv[linewidth=2]{thmb}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{thma}
blabla
\end{thma}
\begin{thmb}
bleble
\end{thmb}
\end{document}
```

My motivation: I want to define several theorem-like environments (such as theorem, proposition, corollary, etc.) with the same style. To do  that, I find natural to use the first way above (i.e., to first define the style by 'mdfdefinestyle' and then use it to define several environments using 'mdtheorem'). Using the second way would require to copy-paste the style parameters in each 'newmdtheoremenv' command.

Comment: how should one help here? they do different things and looking at the code this is intended. But I would recommend to drop mdframed, it is not longer maintained. Use tcolorbox instead.

Comment: Thanks for your remark. I edited the question to add the motivation.

Comment: I agree with @UlrikeFischer, using `tcolorbox` would be better (although I find tcolorbox to powerful and thus to "bloat", but anyway). What you could instead do is to to define a custom command with one argument for your theorem environment.